# MacOS /dev/null permission denied

Tags: linux, bash, macos, sh, mamp

I've been looking around for this issue that i have been seeing lately.
I'm working on a project where i write all output to the /dev/null void.
My problem is that i get a permission denied while i'm using the root user.
BTW: the dev/null has the correct permissions (crw-rw-rw-).

What i noticed is that when MAMP is running and i am developing my other project which is not using MAMP i get a permission denied on the /dev/null.

Can the /dev/null handle multiple processes using it ?
My thoughts are that MAMP is using the void and other processes don't get permission to it. I've been looking around for a fix but i can't find any documentation on MAMP using the dev/null whatsoever.

FYI: i'm writing to the void using a bash script.

```
export SUDO_UID=$1
export SUDO_GID=$2
shift 2
echo PID=$$
$@ > /dev/null
```

Things i have tried:

- Restart computer (dev/null get's recreated at that point)
- Change the permissions to the dev/null
- Remove and remake the dev/null
- Close MAMP (this works but i have to have a fallback)

A simple fix would be to say: "Just close MAMP" but when i'm distributing this dmg file i want to be sure i'm able to write to the dev/null and not just throw an error and close my executable.

If anyone would be able to point me into the right direction about multiple processes writing to /dev/null or has another way to write to the void.

Everything is welcome.
Kind regards

Comment: [bash-dev-null-permission-denied](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146633/bash-dev-null-permission-denied) or [cannot-access-dev-null-permission-denied-although-crw-rw-rw-1-root-root-1-3](https://superuser.com/questions/814593/cannot-access-dev-null-permission-denied-although-crw-rw-rw-1-root-root-1-3), may help?

Comment: Already tried that as stated in my question. Thanks for your input though

Comment: can you give full output of `ls -ld /dev /dev/null`

Comment: dr-xr-xr-x  3 root  wheel      4297  5 jun 19:08 /dev

crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel    3,   2  5 jun 19:14 /dev/null

Comment: I don't think it's an issue related to permissions. I think it's rather something taking the use of dev/null and not letting any other programs use it.

Comment: i've just seen your comments, however from the last answer of the first link i've referenced, see also `man mknod`, it seems for OpenBSD (maybe the same as OSX), /dev/null major and minor should be 2 2. or from comment maybe `cd /dev; ./MAKEDEV std`

Comment: Just in case: https://superuser.com/q/239029/284722

Comment: If you have permission to /dev/null then by default multiple processes may be writing simultaneously. So your problem is something else. Your permissions look good. Also I can't reproduce your problem. So please update your question with a script that produces the error.